# Trouble formatting image gallery CSS

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I am trying to build a very simplistic image gallery however, when I add additional images it breaks the layout on the page. I have attached the html, css and image of the problem.

I am self taught so there could be some very obvious and basic errors in there but any help identifying and explaining would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

[gallery css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB2Wl.png)

[gallery html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDDzA.png)

[resulting disaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjDj4.png)

Comment: Hello. To get help, you need to put your code in text, but not a link to images.

Comment: CSS grid would be a great candidate to use for your gallery layout. If you post your code would be glad to help set that up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flexbox** for the images alignment instead of float.
Try to replace the float property for the elements with class name`.Gallery` with:

```js
.Gallery {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here you can find the basic concepts of flexbox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Hey - Worked like a CHARM! Thank you very much for your help with this.